# Create like and dislike with nodejs and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, crud

For my training project, I have to create the controllers for the 'like' and 'dislikes' with the verb post.

Could someone suggest me how to proceed for this?

It's my schema and model:

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    
    const sauceSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        userId: {type: String, required: true},
        name: {type: String, required: true},
        manufacturer: {type: String, required: true},
        description: {type: String, required: true},
        mainPepper: {type: String, required: true},
        imageUrl: {type: String, required: true},
        heat: {type: Number, required: true},
        likes: {type: Number, required: true, default:0},
        dislikes: {type: Number, required: true, default:0},
        usersLiked: {type: [String]},
        usersDisliked: {type: [String]},
    });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Sauce', sauceSchema);
```

Comment: So What's the error you got?

Comment: Why are you keeping like and userLiked and same for dislikes? What you want to achieve can you be more specific?

Comment: I want to increment in the database, like and dislike and user id.
When this one clicks on the button.